# Symfony, Request cannot find the service

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to run my code I get the following error message :

> Cannot autowire argument $request of
> "App\Controller\AppController::formulaire()": it references class
> "symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" but no such service exists.

I don't understand as I followed tutorial and checked on symfony documentation and it looks fine!

my code is :

```
/**
     * @Route("/form", name="form")
     */
    public function formulaire(Request $request)
    {
        $application = new Applications();
        $candidat = new Candidats();
        $annexe = new Annexes();

        $formAnnexe = $this->createFormBuilder($annexe)
                            ->add("fichier")
                            ->getForm();

        $formCandidat = $this->createFormBuilder($candidat)
                            ->add("nom")
                            ->add("prenom")
                            ->add("email")
                            ->getForm();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($application)
                    ->add("poste", ChoiceType::class, [
                        'choices'  => [
                        'Choisissez un poste ...' => null,
                        'Chef de Projet' => 'Chef de Projet',
                        'Secrétaire' => 'Secrétaire',
                        'Assistant' => 'Assistant',
                        ],
                    ])
                    ->add('pdf', FileType::class, [
                        'label' => 'Fiche de candidature (PDF)',
        
                        // unmapped means that this field is not associated to any entity property
                        'mapped' => false,
        
                        // make it optional so you don't have to re-upload the PDF file
                        // every time you edit the Product details
                        'required' => false,

                        'constraints' => [
                            new File([
                                'maxSize' => '1024k',
                                'mimeTypes' => [
                                    'application/pdf',
                                    'application/x-pdf',
                                ],
                                'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid PDF document',
                            ])
                        ]
                    ])
                    ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        return $this->render('app/form.html.twig', [
            
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'formCandidat' => $formCandidat->createView(),
            'formAnnexe' => $formAnnexe->createView(),
        
            
        ]);
    }
   
}
```

And I use the followings :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Applications;
use App\Entity\Candidats;
use App\Entity\Annexes;
use symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\Common\Cersistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
```

Everthing was fine until I added (Request $request)

Does anyone knows what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a typo when you import the `Request` class.
you import from this namespace `use symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;` with lower-case `s`.
any import namespaces are case-sensitive.
use this namespace. `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`